# Use custom names for IHostingEnvironment

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

We are running ASP.NET Core and using IHostingEnvironment eagerly.

Because of conventions in our organization, our environment names don't match those of the default IHostingEnvironment implementation.

To work around this we have made the following extension methods:

```
public static class HostingEnvironmentExtensions
{
        public static bool IsProd(this IHostingEnvironment env) => env.IsEnvironment("prod");            

        public static bool IsTest(this IHostingEnvironment env) => env.IsEnvironment("test");                 
}
```

This works fine, but feels kind of dangerous because the default methods of `IsProduction` and `IsStaging` now don't work the way you'd expect.

What is the proper way to deal with environment names being different from the ASP.NET Core defaults?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could solve this by creating your own implementation. I created my own `IWorkingEnvironment` interface like this:

```
public interface IWorkingEnvironment
{
    string EnvironmentName { get; set; }
}
```

And my own 'known' environment names:

```
public static class EnvironmentNames
{
    public static readonly string Local = nameof(Local);

    public static readonly string Dev = nameof(Dev);

    public static readonly string Test = nameof(Test);

    public static readonly string Prod = nameof(Prod);
}
```

Followed by the extension methods on `IWorkingEnvironment`:

```
public static class WorkingEnvironmentExtensions
{
    public static bool IsLocal(this IWorkingEnvironment environment)
    {    
        return environment.EnvironmentName == EnvironmentNames.Local;
    }

    public static bool IsDev(this IWorkingEnvironment environment)
    {    
        return environment.EnvironmentName == EnvironmentNames.Dev;
    }

    // etc...
}
```

Then my implementation of `IWorkingEnvironment` using the ASP.NET `IHostingEnvironment`:

```
public class AspNetWorkingEnvironment : IWorkingEnvironment
{
    private readonly IHostingEnvironment _hostingEnvironment;

    public AspNetWorkingEnvironment(IHostingEnvironment hostingEnvironment)
    {
        _hostingEnvironment = hostingEnvironment;
    }

    public string EnvironmentName => _hostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName;
}
```

Now all we have to do is register the `AspNetWorkingEnvironment` as implementation of `IWorkingEnvironment` (using a singleton lifetime) in our dependency injection container:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddSingleton<IWorkingEnvironment, AspNetWorkingEnvironment>();

    // etc...
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I would really have liked to be able to use IHostingEnvironment, since it means that new developers wouldn't need any knowledge of which interface to use, but I suppose this is the best approach with the current (lack of) configurability of HostingEnvironment

Answer (score 1):

The cleanest way would be to extend your own type that implements `IHostingEnvironment` and inject it into your controllers and services.

But, if you insist on relying on the built-in methods, you can (somewhat dangerously) override the `string` values in the `EnvironmentName` type to match your custom values:

```
public Startup(IHostingEnvironment env)
{
    var envNameType = typeof(EnvironmentName);

    envNameType.GetField(EnvironmentName.Development).SetValue(null, "dev");
    envNameType.GetField(EnvironmentName.Production).SetValue(null, "prod");
    envNameType.GetField(EnvironmentName.Staging).SetValue(null, "stag");

    // given that current environment name == "prod", both would evaluates to 'true'
    var isInProd = env.IsEnvironment("prod");
    var isProd = env.IsProduction();

    // ...
}
```

Internally, the built-in `IsEnvironment()` method is relying on the values from that `EnvironmentName` to determine the environment name.

See [Source](https://github.com/aspnet/Hosting/blob/b6da89f54cff11474f17486cdc55c2f21f2bbd6b/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.Abstractions/HostingEnvironmentExtensions.cs#L74)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Like you said yourself, this is kinda a mad scientist approach, and basically there is no "proper way of doing this"